# Output JSON image in listView

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I tried uploading an image using JSON. I create a link to image in JSON. Many times I tried to fix my problem, but with no success.

Is there a mistake in my use of `DownloadImageTask` in  My adapter `Adapter` ?

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    newsList = new ArrayList<News>();

    //this is i take json image
    new NewsAsynkTask().execute();
}

public class NewsAsynkTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //code
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

    //this i run adapter
        NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, newsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

My adapter Adapter

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {
    ArrayList<News> ArrayListNews;
    int Resourse;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater vi;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<News> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        ArrayListNews = objects;
        Resourse = resource;
        this.context = context;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(Resourse, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagenews);
            holder.nameNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namenews);
            holder.dayNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.daynews);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(ArrayListNews.get(position).getImageNews());
        holder.nameNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getNameNews());
        holder.dayNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getDayNews());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView nameNews;
        public TextView dayNews;
    }

    //this is i try load image. I using wrong somthing, please help me
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        ImageLoader imgLoader;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            final String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {


                Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //this is class on this [link][1]. I try use simple, it work. But here dont work
                        imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
                        imgLoader.DisplayImage(urldisplay, bmImage);
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I tried uploading an image using JSON`. Can be. But there is nothing in your code that does that. And why would it be relevant as you want to download images for the listview.  `I create a link to image in JSON. `. Can be but nowhere in your code we can see that. `Many times I tried to fix my problem`. You did not tell which problem you have.

Comment: Please tell what your first asynctask does. Also tell what your second asynctask should do.